# AOSP - Error: Overriding commands for target (...), previously defined at (...)

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, building

I'm trying to build AOSP for non - supported device `(surnia - Moto E2 2015 LTE)`.

I solved lots of problems earlier but now I have one that I can't avoid. I saw a lot of people had that problem, but their was just warning...

What can I do? Or could you help me finding surnia device tree (but for stock AOSP)?

```
[100% 441/441] writing build rules ...
FAILED: 
build/make/core/Makefile:28: error: overriding commands for target `out/target/product/surnia/system/vendor/lib/libHevcSwDecoder.so', previously defined at build/make/core/base_rules.mk:480
19:07:53 ckati failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (01:22 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently encountered a similar error. It's because of a duplicate entry in `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` which both are trying to copy some file to the same destination `out/target/product/surnia/system/vendor/lib/libHevcSwDecoder.so`. This will cause en error.

For me, the duplicate entry was in the following file:

```
<AOSP_ROOT>/vendor/google_devices/<DEVICE_CODENAME>/<DEVICE_CODENAME>-vendor-blobs.mk
```

For you, I think you should be looking for `surnia-vendor-blobs.mk`. Open this file and find the `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` entry that has the destination `out/target/product/surnia/system/vendor/lib/libHevcSwDecoder.so`, then you can remove it to resolve the error.

This is a workaround, unfortunately I couldn't figout out what's the root problem.

by the way, Welcome Peter to Stack Overflow!

Comment: But now, I have problem with...
```ninja: 'out/target/product/surnia/kernel', needed by 'out/target/product/surnia/boot.img', missing and no known rule to make it

```

Comment: @PeterPkp123 This error means that you should have a `device-common.mk` file in `<AOSP_ROOT>/device/.../surnia/` that defines how to build/copy the kernel image for the device, but it sounds like that you don't have this make file or it doesn't have any recipe for `out/target/product/surnia/kernel`.

Comment: Shoud I build kernel myself? I don't see any instructions in device.mk and no device-common.mk file ;/

Comment: @PeterPkp123 The kernel build tree isn't included in AOSP build tree. It's usually prebuilt  and its image is in `/device/...` directory.

Comment: I solved that problem, but I have new one :P

`
FAILED: ninja: 'out/target/product/surnia/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr', needed by 'out/target/product/surnia/obj/EXECUTABLES/stml0xx_intermediates/STML0XX/stml0xx.o', missing and no known rule to make it
11:19:25 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (03:35 (mm:ss)) ####
`

Is there any way to solve it? I just don't know what to do, 100th error in that day :P

Comment: @PeterPkp123 You actually shouldn't be fixing these errors, you should instead look for a full build tree that has make files to build AOSP for your device. Did you check out [LineageOS](https://github.com/LineageOS) build tree? Does it have make files for `surnia`? Also you can check [`android-prepare-vendor`](https://github.com/anestisb/android-prepare-vendor).

Comment: I'm using now everything from lineageOS build trees. I checked every surnia device tree I think and Lineage had the smallest count of errors  I downloaded vendor files, kernel, prebuild Kernel zImage and now I'm at the last step before processing that thousands of file when building... I don't know what to do, because surnia is not supported device now

Comment: @PeterPkp123 Sorry, I don't know how to fix that error.

Answer (score 3):

add this flag "BUILD_BROKEN_DUP_RULES := true" in your BoardConfig.mk this work for me

Comment: Could you please shortly explain why or how this fixes the problem?