# Error: overriding commands for base_rules.mk in AOSP 10

Tags: android, android-source

Getting following error while building AOSP 10 by command **make -j$(nproc)**

> FAILED:
> build/make/core/base_rules.mk:480: error: overriding commands for target
> `out/target/product/device_name/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_swiftshader.so',
> previously defined at build/make/core/base_rules.mk:480
> 09:57:25 ckati failed with: exit status 1

Added new device for a product and follow the instruction which was give by android [link](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device)

Actually with same setup in android 9 it was working.

One more point, If I again try to build then I got following error

> ninja: warning: premature end of file; recovering FAILED: ninja:
> external/ninja/src/deps_log.cc:631: bool DepsLog::RecordId(Node *):
> Assertion `node->path().size() > 0' failed. 10:20:28 soong bootstrap
> failed with: exit status 139

Any suggestion would help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which branch did you check out? Did you change one of the files that the build error mentions?

Comment: I am working on android-10 aosp branch. No I didn't change into above mentioned files

Comment: This question seems similar, and has an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543058/aosp-error-overriding-commands-for-target-previously-defined-at

Answer (score 0):

`rm -r out/soong/.bootstrap` works for me.