# How to fix error "overriding commands for target `[file]', previously defined at [file]"?

Tags: android, build

I'm trying to build Pixel Experience AOSP ROM for my Lenovo Tab 4 8 Plus. I have build Android 9 successfully with the help of unofficial trees, kernel, and vendor, but for some reason Android 10 is failing to build, giving me this error:

```
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:525: error: overriding commands for target `/home/chas/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/TB8704/system/vendor/etc/init/android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1-service.rc', previously defined at build/make/core/base_rules.mk:525
```

Any ways I can fix this?

Comment: Bump bump bump.

Comment: Hello hello anyone there?

Answer (score 0):

I can just reference this answer, it's a workaround but the cause is still unknown to me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59543277/8008892